# Conformal Map from Domain $D$(where $D$ is bounded by $\{z=x+iy,y=1/x,x>0\}$, $2+2i\in D$) to upper Half Plane

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry, hyperbolic-functions

I am trying to find the Conformal Map from Domain $D$(where $D$ is bounded by $\{z=x+iy,y=1/x,x>0\}$, $2+2i\in D$) to upper Half Plane $\mathbb{H}:=\{w:Im(w)>0\}$, I am using $z+1/z$ map but could't figure out [striped region to upper half plane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXklu.jpg)